# Kill only the chromedriver instance, started while running the python script and not others

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to kill the chromedriver process started while running the particular script and not the other chromedriver process which would be running from other scripts. Is this possible?whilr using OS.system("taskkill /f /Im chromedriver.exe"), it kills all the chrome driver processes.i am working on selenium with python.I dnt want to kill the browser session, so not using driver.quite or close or dispose. Just want to kill the chromedriver.exe started while the script was run

Comment: `driver.quit()` should do what you're asking for

Comment: Hi.. I dnt want to kill the browser session, just the corresponding chromedriver.exe

Comment: Did you get your answers or still need help?

Comment: The link mentioned above did help me. But with selenium launched browser, and checking for the pid, gives the driver pid and not the browser pid. Is it possible to get the browser pid ie launched, when the python script is run, I just want that pid and not the whole set of pid corresponding to all the process running for chrome.exe, no problem I think I will raise another question.Thank you for your help.